# Accessing class array in main

Tags: c++, arrays

So I'm doing a cinema booking project for college,but we havn't covered inheritance yet.
I want to access my array in the main,it is in a seperate class.I want to access the array when a case is met.

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "cinema.cpp"
#include "screen.cpp"
#include "screen.cpp"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int loop=1;
    string Film;
    int inputFilm;
    while(loop==1)
    {
        cout << "Please select film \n ";
        cout<<"\n\n";
        cout << " 1: Godzilla  [Screen 1] \n 2: Waking Life  [Screen 2] \n 3: Saving Private Ryan  [Screen 3] \n 4: LOTR  [Screen 4] \n 5: The Departed  [Screen 5] \n 6: Knocked Up  [Screen 6] \n";

        cout << "\n Enter a screen number";
        cin >> inputFilm;
        switch(inputFilm)
        {
        case 1: 
            Film = "Godzilla";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            Film = "Waking Life";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            Film = "Saving Private Ryan";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        case 4:
            Film = "LOTR";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        case 5:
            Film = "The Departed";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        case 6:
            Film = "Knocked Up";
            cout <<"You have chosen: "+Film;
            cout << "\n";
            break;
        }
        break;
    cout << "Please eneter a seat row";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Class that contains array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "cinema.h"
using namespace std;

cinema::cinema()
{
    string ScreenArray [6];
    ScreenArray [0] = "Godzilla";
    ScreenArray [1] = "Waking Life";
    ScreenArray [2] = "Saving Private Ryan";
    ScreenArray [3] = "LOTR";
    ScreenArray [4] = "The Departed";
    ScreenArray [5] = "Knocked UP";
    address = "Golden Island Shopping Center";
}
string cinema::getAddres()const
{
    return address;
}
//int cinema::NumOfScreens()const
//{
//  return NumOfScreens;
//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using classes can simplify things, but you don't need them here (unless the assignment calls for it).

The array in the constructor of `Cinema` is local to that constructor function.

Just move it to `main`.

---

By the way, `main` absolutely *must* have result type `int`. Microsoft Visual C++ allows `void`, and their examples often have `void` result type for `main`, but that's non-standard; it's just Microsoft's thing to be non-standard in subtle ways that help with vendor lock-in. Apart from effectively limiting the code to that particular compiler, it's also a sign of the absolutely newbie, which you cease to be once you replace `void` with `int`. ;-)

---

Addendum:
Here's an example of code to do what I think you're trying to do so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template< class Item, int n >
auto n_items( Item (&)[n] ) -> int { return n; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    string const    movies[]    =
    {
        "Godzilla",
        "Waking Life",
        "Saving Private Ryan",
        "LOTR",
        "The Departed",
        "Knocked UP"
    };
    string const address = "Golden Island Shopping Center";

    cout << "Welcome to the " << address << " cinema!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for( int i = 0;  i < n_items( movies );  ++i )
    {
        cout << i + 1 << ": " << movies[i] << endl;
    }

    int choice;
    cout << "Film number (or 0 for none)? ";  cin >> choice;
    if( cin.fail() )
    {
        cout << "Oops, I couldn't understand that number specification." << endl;
    }
    else if( !(0 <= choice && choice <= n_items( movies ) ) )
    {
        cout << "Sorry, the number must be 0 or a valid film number." << endl;
    }
    else if( choice == 0 )
    {
        // Whatever -- exit?
    }
    else
    {
        int const index = choice - 1;
        cout << "You chose '" << movies[index] << "'." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok and just return 0? 
Btw my assignment does call for classes to be outside the main cpp.

Comment: move the array, not the constructor function